# C# TCP получение пакета

Tags: c#

Суть такова: клиент подключается к асинхронному серверу, отправляет пакет авторизации(PROTOCOL_LOGIN_REQ):

```
string login = "admin";//логин пользователя
int loginLength = login.Count();
string password = "123456";//пароль пользователя
int passwordLength = password.Count();
Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(login);
Byte[] data2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
stream.WriteByte(100);//опкод
stream.WriteByte((byte)loginLength);
stream.WriteByte((byte)passwordLength);
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
stream.Write(data2, 0, data2.Length);
```

Сервер разбирает пакет, сверяет полученные данные с данными в бд, затем отправляет пакет с информацией об авторизации:

```
namespace LoginServer.Network.Packets.Server
{
    public class PROTOCOL_LOGIN_ACK
    {
        public PROTOCOL_LOGIN_ACK(TcpClient client, int Result)
        {
            client.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)101);//опкод
            client.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)Result);//результат
            /* Если результат не равен 3, то закрываем соединение с клиентом. */
            if (Result != 3)
            {
                client.Close();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

При успешной авторизации результат будет равен трем, но это сейчас не так важно.
Проблема в том, что клиент не дожидается получения пакета от сервера и читает пустой буфер:

```
// буфер для приема сообщений
data = new Byte[100000];
int i = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
if (i > 0)
{
    switch (data[0])
    {
        case 101:
            switch (data[1])
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine("PASSWORD_NO");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("MAIL_NOT_VERIFY");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("ACCOUNT_BLOCKED");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS_AUTH");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
         case 102:
            break;
         default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Нет никакой гарантии что данные, записанные одним куском, так же одним куском и дойдут. Не читайте данные в буффер руками, используйте `BinaryReader`. При чтении через Reader код будет ждать, пока придет ровно столько байт, сколько вы хотели прочитать. Попробуйте что-то вроде:

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream());
byte opcode = reader.ReadByte(); // ACCOUNT_BLOCKED
// if (opcode == 3)
byte messageSize = reader.ReadByte(); // вычитает длину

// вычитает ровно messageSize байт
string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(reader.ReadBytes(messageSize));
```

Comment: извините я не силен в потоках, но как `reader.ReadByte()`  (2-ая строка) узнает сколько байт читать?

Comment: @adamshakhabov ReadByte всегда читает ровно один байт.