# Из потока читаются не все данные

Tags: c#, потоки-данных

Вопрос следующий. Клиент пишет в поток строку байт. Сервер её принимает. Но принимает он только часть, т.е. часть байт в конце строки просто пропадает куда-то. 
Объект потока - `NetworkStream stream = null;` и `NetworkStream clientStream;`. Количество байт, которое пишется и читается одинаковое. В чем тут ошибка?

Функция отправки запроса (клиент):

```
public int SendRequest(string command, EditorForm data)
{
    ConstructRequest(command, data);

    stream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request), 0, request.Length);
    return 0;
}
```

Функция приёма запроса (сервер):

```
public string RecieveRequest()
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[64];

            int countBytes = 0;
            do
            {
                countBytes = clientStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                builder.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, countBytes));
            }
            while (clientStream.DataAvailable);
            data = builder.ToString();

            DistructRequest();

            return data;
        }
```

Comment: clientStream.Read читает не столько байт, сколько отправил сервер, а столько, сколько успело дойти на клиент (и наоборот). Если вам нужно прочитать строгое количество байт - оберните Stream в BinaryReader/BinaryWriter

Comment: Вот пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/772159/177221

Comment: В методе Write функци GetBytes формирует один массив, а длину вы указываете от другого. По всей видимости массив из GetBytes имеет длину больше, чем значение request.Length